# Intent insert or edit prefilled address field in contact

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

I want to request an Intent of Contact with `Insert_OR_Edit` Action, need to pre-filled some field example Postal address, I can able to pre filled Organisation field but not able to do the same with any other field

[Reference link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html#DATA)

Need To insert "Address" field pro-grammatically through intent

Comment: You're going to need to provide some more information to get useful help from this community.  For example: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? What is or is not working as expected?

Comment: Nice of you to add the details for him, @hot. Hopefully you've also given him some guidance on asking better questions in the future as well...

Answer (score 3):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, getName());
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY, getCompany());
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, getEmail());
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, getPhone());
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, getAddress());
    startActivity(intent);
```

It will prefill mentioned Fields with your information provided.

[image: Prefilled contact fields]

Answer (score 1):

Here are the [Contacts specific Intent fields](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html)

Something like the below might do you well, if i understand your question correctly?

```
Intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, "address");
```